# Moving (instead of showing) div in Angular animation

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gXk5MAZWCozrTDeLlThC?p=preview) I have an Angular animation that shows up and slides in a div from the right. What I need is a 'drawer' effect where the div edge is shown for the user to click on it, and only then the div will slide in. This means that initially the div should be partially shown. Since the original animation is done from hide to show (instead of from show to show) I don't know how to approach this. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.panel{
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
right: -2px;

}

.panel.ng-hide {
  right: -200px;
}
.panel.ng-hide-add, .panel.ng-hide-remove {
  /* this is required as of 1.3x to properly
     apply all styling in a show/hide animation */
  transition: 0s linear all;
}


.panel.ng-hide-add-active, .panel.ng-hide-remove-active {
/* -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
*/
transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}
.panel.ng-show-add-active {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
 Show <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" />
 <div class="panel" ng-show="checked" 
            style="border:1px solid #dddddd;background:orange;width:200px">
      <input type="checkbox" /> Charts <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> Reports <br />
      <input type="checkbox" /> Files <br />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like the SideNav on Android, you should try Angular Material and use the already implemented [SideNav](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/#/demo/material.components.sidenav) instead of creating your own.

If not, try to [translate](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) the div by adding this to your CSS:

```
div {
  transform: translate(-50px,0px);
}
```